# flask render_html arguments

Tags: dataframe, flask

I have a page that outputs several html tables from dataframes.
However the number of tables is variable.

How can I rendre a list of dataframes in flask?

Here is what I do for one table:

```
return render_template("test.html", title='Title', form=form, table1= table1.to_html(index=False, table_id='table1', float_format="{:,.2f}".format))
```

and is the HTML part:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="table1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table1-tab">
    {{ table1|safe }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a dictionary with all of variables in your endpoint python file.

For example:

```
tables = []
# another code

if table1:   # Maybe with HTML format using Markup or something similar.
    tables.append(table1)
if table2:
    tables.append(table2)

# another code

vals = {
   'form': form,
   'title': "Title",
   'tables': tables
}

return render_template("test.html", **vals)
```

In your template you can have:

```
<div class="...">
    {% for t in tables %}
         <div class="...">{{ t }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

From python file you can give the pane activated and the rest of HTML attributes for each tab pane, depending what of them is included in the tables list variable. Could be a simple solution but it can work.

Kind regards.